# Lower bound on sum of independent heavy-tailed random variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, limits-and-convergence, lower-bounds, large-deviations

I have a sum of $n$ i.i.d random variables $X_i$ such that $E[X_i] = 0$,$\mathrm{E}[|X_i|^{1 + \delta}]$ exists for some $0 < \delta < 1$ but $\mathrm{E}[|X_i|^{1 + \delta+ \epsilon}]$ does not exists for any $\epsilon > 0$.

I would like to ask if it is possible to provide a lower bound for $P(|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i| > A\sqrt{n})$, showing that this term converges to $1$ when $n$ approaches infinity.

I am aware that when $X_i$ obeys the tail balance condition, we would have $\frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{a_n}$ converges to a $\alpha-$stable distribution for proper scaling factor $a_n$. So I am mostly interested in the case where the tail balance condition does not hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly. All you need is $EX^2=+\infty$. Then the characteristic function $f_X(t)$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-|f(t)|}{t^2}=+\infty$, so for every finite interval $I\subset \mathbb R$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_I|f(t/\sqrt n)|^n\,dt=0$ and the usual Fourier trickery finishes the story. Of course, the efficient lower bound would require some quantitative information about the speed of divergence of the second moment: if you have essentially the uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$ combined with some large value dust of extremely low probability (which can still blow up any moment you like), then you'll have to wait quite long time before the spreading effect kicks in.

Edit: Just to explain the "Fourier trickery". The story is that if you have some *smooth non-negative function $g$ with compact support that is identically $1$ on $[-A,A]$, then $P(|X|\le A)\le Eg(X)=c\int_{\mathbb R}\widehat g(t)f_X(-t)$, so if you know that $\int|f_X|$ is small over a long interval where $\widehat g$ is still noticeable, then you can conclude that this probability is small and, therefore, $P(|X|>A)$ is close to $1$.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is very helpful but I am not quite aware of the Fourier transformation techniques you mention. Can you please give me some reference on this?

Comment: After some second thought, I realize this is exactly utilizing the inversion formula of characteristic function! This is truly a great answer! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I found an error in my previous deduction. For now, if the c.d.f of $\sum_i X_i/\sqrt{n}$ is $F_n$, I am only able to prove for any $C > 0$, $|\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{sin(Cx)}{Cx} dF_n(x)| \to_n 0$. I am not sure whether this is enough to show the lower bound.

Comment: @KaiyueWen I added more details. Is it clear now?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit how does $EX^2=+\infty$ imply $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-|f(t)|}{t^2}=+\infty$? It looks like it should be a simple Taylor expansion but I cannot make it work (not really sure how to deal with the absolute value $|f(t)|$).

Comment: @SaliniMendisi Do it for $\Re f(t)$ instead of $|f(t)|$ first and then just combine it with $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|\Im f(t)|}{|t|}=0$, which you can obtain from the mean zero property (and the existence of expectation, of course).

Comment: Thank you! But I am still confused about how I should bound $\int_{\mathrm{R}/I} \hat g(t) f_X(-t) dt$ with $I$ being a finite integral. If we choose $g$ as the indicator function $I(-A,A)$, then $\hat g(t) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{2sin(At)}{t}$ and it seems that $\int_{\mathrm{R}/I} |\hat g(t)| dt$ will diverge for any $I$. Maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: @KaiyueWen Didn't I say "*smooth*"? (meaning $C^\infty$). Of course, if you make the choice $g=I(-A,A)$, you'll not get much, but why should you? :-)

Comment: I see. I am not aware that will make a difference! Let me ponder on it. Thank you!

Comment: @KaiyueWen The Fourier transform of a smooth function decays faster than any power, so the integrability at $\infty$ becomes trivial. :)

Comment: Wow, that is a wonderful property I didn't know about before. Thank you! I think this completely solves my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142118/discussion-between-kaiyue-wen-and-fedja).